# Retrieve an SSAS Member Property in a Reporting Services report

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I am new to SSAS and am trying to show the 'Phone Number' attribute on a Reporting Services report. I have not been able to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
SELECT 
{
   [Agent].[Agent Key].[Agent Key],

   DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME.[Agent].[Agent Key].[Phone Number]
}  ON ROWS,
```

The error I am getting is Query (15, 1) Parser: The syntax for 'DIMENSION' is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DIMENSION PROPERTIES` clause has to be directly before the `ON ROWS`, i. e. after the closing brace, and the properties should be separated by commas, not by a dot, i. e.:

```
SELECT ... 
       ON COLUMNS,
       {
       [Agent].[Agent Key].[Agent Key],
       }  
       DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION,
                            MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME,
                            [Agent].[Agent Key].[Phone Number]
ON ROWS
FROM [YourCube]
```

However, even if the syntax would be correct, I am not sure you could easily access tho row axis member properties in Reporting Services. But you can use a workaround: Define a calculated measure that returns the property. Calculated measures do not need to return numbers, they can also return strings. You would do that as follows:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[Phone Number] AS
     [Agent].[Agent Key].CurrentMember.Properties("Phone Number")
SELECT { Measures.[Phone Number] }
       ON COLUMNS,
       [Agent].[Agent Key].[Agent Key].Members
       ON ROWS
FROM [YourCube]
```

Comment: @YolandaHerrera If my answer solved your question, you should mark it as the correct answer by clicking on the check mark in the left of it.